# data export import module how to keep alias drupal

Tags: path-aliases, importing-exporting

I found `data_export_import` module very useful, however. It does not `import/export` url aliases and block content. Why I could live without the block content, I really would like to have nice way to `import/export` url aliases. Which module or which approach would you recommend to handle `import/export` url aliases? the same for blocks.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i did is created gradle script that import/exports url as following:

```
         task exportUrl(type:Exec){
            doFirst{println "exporting Urls..."}
                executable "sh"
                args "-c", "mysqldump -u ${user} -p${pass} ${db} url_alias>sites/default/files/data_export_import_${view}/url_${db}_import.sql"
         }


 task importUrl(type:Exec){
     doFirst{println "exporting Urls..."}
         executable "sh"
         args "-c", "mysql -u ${user} -p${pass} -h localhost ${db}<sites/default/files/data_export_import_${view}/url_${db}_import.sql"
  }
```

it works well because i can also use drush to do the node import/export in the gradle script as well.

```
            task exportNodes(type:Exec){
                   doFirst{println "exporting Nodes..."}
                       executable "sh"
                       args "-c", "drush dei-ex nodes --content-types=address,article,blog[other content types]"
                }

task importNodes() << {
       def dir = new File("sites/default/files/data_export_import/nodes").list().toList()
       for (fileName in dir ) {
              println "ipmorting file ${fileName}..."
                    exec {
                        executable "sh"
                        args "-c", "drush dei-im nodes --file=${fileName}"
                    }
       }
}
```

I hope its useful for anyone

Comment: continuing finding solutions on this path alias/menu import-export problem http://margotskapacs.com/2014/04/solving-menu-import-issue-when-featuring-sample-data-in-drupal

Answer (score 1):

This article is a good one: http://margotskapacs.com/2014/04/solving-menu-import-issue-when-featuring-sample-data-in-drupal

However I would like to point out that Part-I and Part-II can be accomplished by the module **menu_import** (https://drupal.org/project/menu_import). It can be done with **drush** (from terminal) like this:

```
drush menu-export $(pwd)/main-menu.txt main-menu
drush menu-import $(pwd)/main-menu.txt main-menu –clean-import
```

The module that you have created for custom aliases (https://github.com/kapasoft-config-scripts/designssquare_alias_path) is a good one too. However I think that it should go as a patch to the module **node_export**: https://drupal.org/project/node_export