# Transfer (export/import) url aliases and menu links automatically

Tags: navigation

I want to transfer/synchronize url aliases and menu links from one site to another. Is there any way (drupal module, drush command, script) to do it automatically? The module [menu_import](https://drupal.org/project/menu_import) looked promising but it does not take care of aliases.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea for solving this issue (at least until a more definite solution is implemented, with uuid etc.) is described in this article:
http://margotskapacs.com/2014/04/solving-menu-import-issue-when-featuring-sample-data-in-drupal/

This is a related issue: [data export import module how to keep alias drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79195/data-export-import-module-how-to-keep-alias-drupal)